# How to get public posts of facebook user based on facebook url without authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-oauth

I am working on asp.net mvc. I am trying to search public facebook posts of a user by the facebook url. i.e. I have a textbox in my webpage in that user will enter his facebook url like **https://www.facebook.com/xxx.yyy** and based on that url i need to find particular user and needs to display all public posts of that user. I have tried with open graph api like,

**https://graph.facebook.com/search?q={username found in url}&type=user**

but it asks me accesstoken. I will get accesstoken only when user was login to facebook but i need to display  user's public posts without asking him for authentication. Please guide me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't necessarily need a User access token to get result from https://graph.facebook.com/search , you can use your [App Access Token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/access-tokens-and-types/) to retrieve the result.
You can also use the same App Access Token to query the public post of the user by calling to Facebook's end point like

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<user-id>/posts
```

Where  is the value specified in your textbox as

```
https://www.facebook.com/<user-id>
```